# How to make an array of textbox value using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am facing problem on this. The value on the textbox can't make an array. It read as string when i check in `console`. Im trying to check the length of it but it reads in string. It was a multiDatepicker. It seems not correct. Kindly see where did i missed?

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datepicker({
  multidate: true
});
        
var arrDate = [];
arrDate.push(document.getElementById("txt_date").value);
console.log(arrDate.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
  <font color="black">Dates: </font>
</label>
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
  <input type='text' class="form-control" name='txt_date' id='txt_date'/>
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: What library are you using for the datepicker component?

Comment: Is this what you asking? `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>`

Comment: A text input value is always a string, you can not directly get an array from that. If you look at the documentation, `multidate` only means that you will get the multiple selected values in string form in the field value, concatenated together with the `multidateSeparator` character in between (comma by default.) So you would need to get this value and _split_ it at this separator character, then you will have your array afterwards.

Comment: Okay ill it...thanks

Comment: Why when i put it in a for loop it get an error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null`

`var dateVal = $('#txt_date').val(); var arrDate = dateVal.split(",");`
`for(var a=0;a<arrDate.length;a++){ alert(arrDate[a]);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use their own API method `getDates`. See the documentation [here](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#getdates)

> getDates
>
> Arguments: None
>
> Returns a list of localized date objects representing the internal
>   date objects of the first datepicker in the selection. For use with
>   multidate pickers.

Use it like this

```
console.log($('#datetimepicker1').datepicker('getDates'));
```

Here is a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/tzwchnek/)